# How to fix Jquery Load() that returns [object Object] when called through an infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if the answer is already somewhere but I searched through Google and I found similar questions but not the answer I'm looking for. So I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/how-to-implement-infinite-scrolling-with-javascript--cms-37055t) to set up a page that displays content as the user scrolls down. What I'm struggling with is how to include html files within the  that's generated through the scrolling. Each html file is called 1.html, 2.html, etc. When I use the Load function (which I found [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) I get [object Object] displayed instead of what's inside the file. How can I fix that?

Here's the code:

```
<div id="card-container">

<div id="loader">
  <div class="skeleton-card"></div>
  <div class="skeleton-card"></div>
  <div class="skeleton-card"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-actions">
  <span>Showing 
    <span id="card-count"></span> of 
    <span id="card-total"></span> cards      
  </span>
</div>



<script>

{literal}
const cardContainer = document.getElementById("card-container");
const cardCountElem = document.getElementById("card-count");
const cardTotalElem = document.getElementById("card-total");
const loader = document.getElementById("loader");

const cardLimit = 99;
const cardIncrease = 9;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(cardLimit / cardIncrease);
let currentPage = 1;

cardTotalElem.innerHTML = 99;

var throttleTimer;
const throttle = (callback, time) => {
  if (throttleTimer) return;

  throttleTimer = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    throttleTimer = false;
  }, time);
};

const getRandomColor = () => {
  const h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

  return `hsl(${h}deg, 90%, 85%)`;
};

const createCard = (index) => {
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";
  card.innerHTML = $('#card').load('test.html #card');;
  card.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  cardContainer.appendChild(card);
};

const addCards = (pageIndex) => {
  currentPage = pageIndex;

  const startRange = (pageIndex - 1) * cardIncrease;
  const endRange =
    currentPage == pageCount ? cardLimit : pageIndex * cardIncrease;

  cardCountElem.innerHTML = endRange;

  for (let i = startRange + 1; i <= endRange; i++) {
    createCard(i);
  }
};

const handleInfiniteScroll = () => {
  throttle(() => {
    const endOfPage =
      window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight;

    if (endOfPage) {
      addCards(currentPage + 1);
    }

    if (currentPage === pageCount) {
      removeInfiniteScroll();
    }
  }, 1000);
};

const removeInfiniteScroll = () => {
  loader.remove();
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleInfiniteScroll);
};

window.onload = function () {
  addCards(currentPage);
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", handleInfiniteScroll);
{/literal}
</script>
```

The {literal} is because I'm using Smarty in any case that's relevant.

I tried this:

```
$("#card").load("test.html");
```

But I still get the same error. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Check the browser developer tools, is `[object Object]` being sent by the server? If so, the server is the issue.

Comment: `card.innerHTML = $('#card').load('test.html #card');` - that assignment to `card.innerHTML` is your problem. That has no place being there - the load method itself already inserts the loaded content into the element that you are calling it on. You need `$('#card').load('test.html #card');` there, and nothing more.

Comment: @CBroe I did that but now there's just nothing displayed. I understand that .load returns an object, is there an array variable or some other way I display the content that .load gets from the file?

Comment: _"I understand that .load returns an object"_ - it just returns the jQuery instance again (because that is necessary for _method chaining_ to work.) If you want to check what your server actually returned for this request, then you can do that by inspecting its details in the network panel of your browser dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> card.innerHTML = $('#card').load('test.html #card');;
> ```

The [load method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) writes the loaded value into the selected element (i.e. what `$('#card')` finds) and returns a jQuery object.

A jQuery object is not a string of HTML.

It is quite unsuitable to be assigned to `innerHTML`.

Remove `card.innerHTML =`.